# Add parameter to OnClientClick window open in Gridview

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview, onclientclick

I am trying to open a new tab when a button from a Gridview is clicked. I want to know how to properly attach the parameter from the Gridview to the URL. The error I get is **the sever tab is not properly formed**. I am not interested in the Response.Write method as I had issues with that and I am already using SelectedIndexChanged for something else.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnViewClient" runat="server" Text="View Client" CssClass="btn"
    OnClientClick="window.open('localhost:5000/test/test.aspx?client_id?='+ <%# Eval("id") %>) +'" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a data-binding expression for that.

```
OnClientClick=<%# "window.open('localhost:5000/test/test.aspx?client_id?=" + Eval("id") + "');" %>
```

And if you do not want to trigger a PostBack also when the button is clicked, add `return false` to it.

```
OnClientClick=<%# "window.open('/test.aspx?client_id?=" + Eval("id") + "'); return false;" %>
```

Comment: I added the extra quotation which was required but I am still getting the server tag error

Comment: This is what I have OnClientClick='<%# "window.open('localhost:5000/test/test.aspx?client_id?=" + Eval("id") + "');"%>' />

Comment: Remove the `'`: `OnClientClick=<%# "wind`